# Remove OS Name from Windows 7 Logon Screen

Tags: windows-7, login

I just installed Windows 7 RTM on one of my systems and was playing around with customizing the Logon screen background.  I thought that the OS name at the bottom was part of the actual graphic, but it showed up on the new graphic I created.

Is there any way to remove this logo from the login?  I'm hoping it's just a registry tweak.
Likely if anyone knows the solution for Vista it will be the same, so please speak up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some steps [to remove it](http://www.beingmanan.com/wp/2008/11/make-vista-look-behave-like-windows-7/):

```
* Download [Logon Screen][2]
* Download & install [LogonVista][3]
* Load the logon which is in the rar file
* Take ownership for basebrd.dll from c:\windows\branding\basebrd\basebrd.dll
* Replace with the given dll
* Logout and see the changes
```

Note: I think that LogonVista references to LogonStudio...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Vista version of [LogonStudio](http://www.stardock.com/products/logonstudio/downloads.asp) from Stardock also works on Windows 7.